# transpose 1D array of leading dimension N

Tags: arrays, matrix, transpose

how can i transpose an 1d array of leading dimension N, without extra space ? any language is fine

Comment: ?? That makes no sense, a 1D array can't be transposed.

Comment: e.g [ a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 b4 ] = [ a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3 a4 b4 ], leading dimension = 4. Every matrix is nothing more then one 1D array

Comment: this is nonsense - if you have a 2D array that you need to transpose then say so. Also mention what platform you're using as I have some fast platform-specific transpose methods if your application is performance-critical.

Comment: Doesn't need to platform-specific but that info is welcome. Yes it can be seen as a 2D array.

Comment: Given your example, I take it you have a 2d matrix stored in a 1d array.  So really, you're asking about transposing a 2d matrix that happens to be stored in a 1d representation.  Correct?

Answer (score 3):

**My solution for 1D in-place Matrix transposition**

```
  mn    = M*N;      /* M rows and N columns */

  q     = mn - 1;

  i = 0;      /* Index of 1D array that represents the matrix */

  do {

    k = (i*M) % q;

    while (k>i) k = (M*k) % q;

    if (k!=i) Swap(k, i);

  } while ( ++i <= (mn -2) );

  /* Update row and column */

  matrix.M = N;

  matrix.N = M;
```

Answer (score 2):

Transposing a non-square matrix in-place represented as a linear array is a bit
of a trick.

Here is a REXX program that performs an in-place transpose of 
a 2D matrix represented in a one
dimensional array of size **M** * **N** where **M** is the number of
rows and
**N** is the of columns in the
non-transposed array. Once transposed, **M** becomes the number of columns and
**N** becomes the number of rows.

```
i = 0                /* linear array index */ 
do j = 1 to N        /* j = 1 to columns of non-transposed array */ 
  do k = 1 to M      /* k = 1 to rows of non-transposed array */ 
    i = i + 1
    t = (k - 1) * N + j 
    do while t < i 
      jp = (t - 1) % M + 1 
      kp = t - (jp - 1) * M 
      t = (kp - 1) * N + jp 
    end 
    if i \= t then say 'exchange('i',' t')'   /* swap elements */
  end 
end
```

The above program displays array elements that must be exchanged to yield a transposed array.

This program will work for any 
sized matrix represented as a linear array where the elements are arranged 
by column then row. For example, an M by N matrix will have its elements arranged as follows:

X<sub>1,1</sub>, X<sub>1,2</sub>, ... X<sub>1,N</sub>, X<sub>2,1</sub>, X<sub>2,2</sub>, ... X<sub>2,N</sub>, ... X<sub>M,N</sub>

The program prints out the linear array indices of the elements that need to be exchanged to yield
a transposed matrix of the form:

X<sub>1,1</sub>, X<sub>2,1</sub>, ... X<sub>M,1</sub>, X<sub>1,2</sub>, X<sub>2,2</sub>, ... X<sub>M,2</sub>, ... X<sub>M,N</sub>

For example, start with M = 4, N = 2 and an array containing:

`A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3, A4, B4`

Perform the following exchanges:

```
exchange(2, 3) 
exchange(3, 5) 
exchange(4, 7) 
exchange(6, 7)
```

and the arrangement becomes:

`A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4`

**How does this work?**

Start with a notation to identify each element in the linear array as:

```
X[i,j,k] 

where: i is the linear array index for an element in X 
       j is the row number for element in X
       k is the column number for element in X
```

Using this notation, an array in row major order can be generated as:

```
i = 0 
do j = 1 to M    /* Row counter */ 
  do k = 1 to N  /* Column counter */ 
    i = i + 1     /* array index of element j, k */ 
    say 'X['i','j','k']' 
  end 
end
```

Note that given values for **j** (row) and **k** (column), **i**, the linear array index for **X<sub>i,j</sub>**, may be calculated as:

```
i = (j - 1) * N + k
```

The transpose of matrix **X** is constructed by exchanging elements 
**X[i,j,k]** with **X[t,k,j]** over the range of **j = 1 to M** and **k = 1 to N** provided **i > t**. In 
essence we exchange all 
row variables for column variables. Using the notation described above, this amounts 
to exchanging linear array elements:

```
exchange(X[i,j,k], X[t,k,j])
```

Given values for **j** and **k** we can calculate the values of **i** and **t** as:

```
   i = (j - 1) * N + k
   t = (k - 1) * M + i
```

Now, proceed through the linear array making the above exchanges as **i** is increased from 1 to M * N. 
Notice that after each iteration all elements of **X** having an index less than or equal to **i** have
been transposed. This is
because each iteration only completes when the correct element has been
exchanged into **X[i]**.

Whenever **i > t**, it means that a prior exchange took place at index **t**. The element at **t** was 
exchanged as indicated above placing it at some new position **t<sup>prime</sup>**. Given an 
index **t**, we may calculate the row major index **t<sup>prime</sup>** as well as the row and 
column numbers associated with it as follows:

j<sup>prime</sup> = (t - 1) % M + 1
k<sup>prime</sup> = t - (j<sup>prime</sup> - 1) * M
t<sup>prime</sup> = (k<sup>prime</sup> - 1) * N + j<sup>prime</sup>

Again, if **t<sup>prime</sup>** is less than **i**, it means that this element was exchanged 
too and we must continue 
with another round of calculations. Set **t** to the calculated **t<sup>prime</sup>** and repeat. Eventually, **i** will 
become less than **t** and the exchange may be done. Basically we follow the element through all of its 
prior exchanges until we find it at **i** or to the right of **i** in the linear array.

Repeat this cycle for each element in the linear array and the matrix will have been transposed.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach is just:

```
for each m
  for each n
    if m != n 
       swap A[m][n] and A[n][m]
```

This only works for square matrices of course. For in-place transpose of rectangular matrices things get a little trickier.