# Matrix operations using code vectorization

Tags: c, matrix, x86, sse, simd

I have written a function to do the transpose of a 4x4 matrix, but I do not know how to extend the code for a matrix *m* x *n*.

Where can I find maybe some sample code on matrix operations with SSE? product, transpose, inverse, etc?

This is the code of transpose 4x4:

```
 void transpose(float* src, int n) {
    __m128  row0,   row1,   row2,   row3;
    __m128 tmp1;
    tmp1=_mm_loadh_pi(_mm_loadl_pi(tmp1, (__m64*)(src)), (__m64*)(src+ 4));
    row1=_mm_loadh_pi(_mm_loadl_pi(row1, (__m64*)(src+8)), (__m64*)(src+12));
    row0=_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp1, row1, 0x88);
    row1=_mm_shuffle_ps(row1, tmp1, 0xDD);

    tmp1=_mm_movelh_ps(tmp1, row1);
    row1=_mm_movehl_ps(tmp1, row1);

    tmp1=_mm_loadh_pi(_mm_loadl_pi(tmp1, (__m64*)(src+ 2)), (__m64*)(src+ 6));
    row3= _mm_loadh_pi(_mm_loadl_pi(row3, (__m64*)(src+10)), (__m64*)(src+14));
    row2=_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp1, row3, 0x88);
    row3=_mm_shuffle_ps(row3, tmp1, 0xDD);

    tmp1=_mm_movelh_ps(tmp1, row3);
    row3=_mm_movehl_ps(tmp1, row3);

    _mm_store_ps(src, row0);
    _mm_store_ps(src+4, row1);
    _mm_store_ps(src+8, row2);
    _mm_store_ps(src+12, row3);
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to transpose MxN matrices in-place (hard) or do you just want to transpose square (NxN) matrices (easy) ?

Comment: theoretically M x N... but an N x N is not bad...

Comment: I don't understand why SSE-ralated questions got down voted. Do you want optimize for SSE or SSE2? [Here](http://www.randombit.net/bitbashing/2009/10/08/integer_matrix_transpose_in_sse2.html) is more optimal solution for transpose 4x4 matrix using SSE2.

Comment: No a 4x4 solution  but a solution general ... at least N x N if not M x N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do a in-place transpose for arbitrary matrices using SIMD efficiently but I do know how to do it for out-of-place.  Let me describe how to do both

**In place transpose**

For in-place transpose you should see Agner Fog's [Optimizing software in C++](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) manual.  See section 9.10 "Cache contentions in large data structures" example 9.5a.  For certain matrix sizes you will see a large drop in performance due to cache aliasing.  See table 9.1 for examples and this [Why is transposing a matrix of 512x512 much slower than transposing a matrix of 513x513?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413855/why-is-transposing-a-matrix-of-512x512-much-slower-than-transposing-a-matrix-of).  Agner gives a way to fix this using loop tiling (similar to what Paul R described) in Example 9.5b.

**Out of place transpose**

See my answer here (the one with the most votes) [What is the fastest way to transpose a matrix in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737298/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-c).  I have not looked into this in ages but let me just repeat my code here:

```
inline void transpose4x4_SSE(float *A, float *B, const int lda, const int ldb) {
    __m128 row1 = _mm_load_ps(&A[0*lda]);
    __m128 row2 = _mm_load_ps(&A[1*lda]);
    __m128 row3 = _mm_load_ps(&A[2*lda]);
    __m128 row4 = _mm_load_ps(&A[3*lda]);
     _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(row1, row2, row3, row4);
     _mm_store_ps(&B[0*ldb], row1);
     _mm_store_ps(&B[1*ldb], row2);
     _mm_store_ps(&B[2*ldb], row3);
     _mm_store_ps(&B[3*ldb], row4);
}

inline void transpose_block_SSE4x4(float *A, float *B, const int n, const int m, const int lda, const int ldb ,const int block_size) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<n; i+=block_size) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j+=block_size) {
            int max_i2 = i+block_size < n ? i + block_size : n;
            int max_j2 = j+block_size < m ? j + block_size : m;
            for(int i2=i; i2<max_i2; i2+=4) {
                for(int j2=j; j2<max_j2; j2+=4) {
                    transpose4x4_SSE(&A[i2*lda +j2], &B[j2*ldb + i2], lda, ldb);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive answer - unfortunately it seems to have been a "drive by" question as the OP has not even returned to look at any answers, but hopefully this will still be useful for future visitors.

Comment: thank you very much for the help! Now I see the code carefully! thanks

Comment: @user3661321, I think Agner's example code is for square matrices.  For the in-place transpose of non-square matrices see Paul R's suggestion: either do it out-of-place or use the follow-the-cycles method at the Wiki link Paul R mentioned.

Comment: @Boson, Also the algorithm out-place is suitable for me,and one question please....why pass as a parameter block size? it makes sense to set it with a value different than 4? What do represent lda and ldb? with lda=m and ldb=n is ok, with other value doesn't work.

Comment: @user3661321, the block size is a value for cache optimization.  Tune it: try e.g. 32 and 64.  lda and ldb are the strides of the matrix.  Normally they are equal to n.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one general approach you can use for transposing an NxN matrix using tiling. You could even use your existing 4x4 transpose and work with a 4x4 tile size:

```
for each 4x4 block in the matrix with top left indices r, c
    if block is on diagonal (i.e. if r == c)
         get block a = 4x4 block at r, c
         transpose block a
         store block a at r, c
    else if block is above diagonal (i.e. if r < c)
         get block a = 4x4 block at r, c
         get block b = 4x4 block at c, r
         transpose block a
         transpose block b
         store transposed block a at c, r
         store transposed block b at r, c
    else // block is below diagonal
         do nothing
    endif
endfor
```

Obviously N needs to be a multiple of 4 for this to work, otherwise you will need to do some additional housekeeping.

As mentioned above in the comments, an MxN *in-place* transpose is hard to do - you need to either use an additional temporary matrix (which effectively makes it a not-in-place transpose) or use the method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition#Non-square_matrices%3a_Following_the_cycles), but this will be much harder to vectorize with SIMD.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand how I can combine the two codes? could you be more specific please...

Comment: In the pseudo code above you can use your 4x4 transpose routine wherever it says "transpose block".