# c++ how to represent a vector as a matrix and transpose it?

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, vector, transpose

I have a vector of size `n`; `n` is power of 2. I need to treat this vector as a matrix `n` = `R`*`C`. Then I need to transpose the matrix.

For example, I have vector: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

I need to find R and C. In this case it would be: 4,2. And treat vector as matrix:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
[7,8]
```

Transpose it to:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

After transposition vector should be: `[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

Is there existing algorithms to perform in-place non-square matrix transposition? I don't want to reinvent a wheel.

My vector is very big so I don't want to create intermediate matrix. I need an in-place algorithm. Performance is very important.

- All modofications should be done in oroginal vector. Ideally algorithm should work with chunks that will fit in CPU cache.
- I can't use iterator because of memory locality. So I need real transposition.
- It does not matter if matrix would be 2x4 or 4x2

Comment: Do you want to change the actual ordering, or just how you access the elements?

Comment: "I need to find R and C." - Neither in your example case  nor in the general case, `R` and `C` can be derived without further information. in your example `R` can be 4 or 2 while `C` can be 2 or 4.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, or it can be 3x3.

Comment: If performance is the case then you could just add a class method that returns a different iterator than the natural one.

Comment: @igor it can't be 3x3 ! OP said n is power of 2 also here 4x2 or 2x4 is never 3x3

Comment: @Igor: `2x4 == 4x2 == 8 != 3x3 == 9`

Comment: @callyalater: I need to change actual ordering

Comment: @MuliYulzary Depends. If you need to access the same transposed matrix multiple times, making a transposed copy wins because cache if the matrix is big enough.

Comment: You could create different iterators to populate the copy in the order you want.

Comment: also check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737298/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-c

Comment: @Pixelchemist: I need to create a matrix as close to square as possible but it does not matter if it 2x4 or 4x2. And I don't want to have it 3x3.

Comment: Besides, if the vector is big, it is pretty unclear if doing this in place is actually faster than just creating a transposed copy.

Comment: @user1209304 The 2x4 transposition flattening will produce a different result than the 4x2 transposition flattening.

Comment: Anyhow, I can't really figure out what you are trying to do. Maybe Eigen can help you, it can transpose stuff and can [interface C-like arrays](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html).

Comment: What I didn't understand was, are you trying to get a vector or a matrix? What type is the output?

Comment: @callyalater it's not important if matrix is 2x4 or 4x2. I understant that result will be different.

Comment: Getting R and C are pretty simple. N is a power of two, and so are R and C. So log2(N) = log2(R)+log2(C), You just need to choose R or C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be divided in two parts. First, find `R` and `C` and then, reshape the matrix. Here is something I would try to do:

Since `n` is a power of `2`, i.e. `n = 2^k` then if `k` is even, we have: `R=C=sqrt(n)`. And if `k` is odd, then `R = 2^((k+1)/2)` and `C=2^((k-1)/2)`.

**Note:** Since you mentioned you want to avoid using extra memory, I have made some editions to my original answer.

The code to calculate `R` and `C` would be something like:

```
void getRandC(const size_t& n, size_t& R, size_t& C)
{
    int k = (int)log2(double(n)),
        i, j;

    if (k & 1)  // k is odd
        i = (j = (k + 1) / 2) - 1;
    else
        i = j = k / 2;

    R = (size_t)exp2(i);
    C = (size_t)exp2(j);
}
```

Which needs C++11. For the second part, in case you want to keep the original vector:

```
void transposeVector(const std::vector<int>& vec, std::vector<int>& mat)
{
    size_t R, C;
    getRandC(vec.size(), R, C);

    // first, reserve the memory
    mat.resize(vec.size());

    // now, do the transposition directly
    for (size_t i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            mat[i * C + j] = vec[i + R * j];
        }
    }
}
```

And, if you want to modify the original vector and avoid using extra memory, you can write:

```
void transposeInPlace(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    size_t R, C;
    getRandC(vec.size(), R, C);

    for (size_t j = 0; R > 1; j += C, R--)
    {
        for (size_t i = j + R, k = j + 1; i < vec.size(); i += R)
        {
            vec.insert(vec.begin() + k++, vec[i]);
            vec.erase(vec.begin() + i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

See [the live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/b1Ruxi62qucWUBeL)

Comment: I like idea how to calculate R and C. But for transposition it require additional memory. I need to do modifications in oroginal vector without creating intermediate result.

Comment: That was a quite good challenge. This code is now really fast and small and seems to meet your goals @user1209304

Comment: Thanks for solution. Functionally it works correct but on big size vectors like 4194304 it works terribly slow. I stopped application after 1 min.

Comment: That is because of the fact that inserting an element into a big vector and erasing another are time-consuming operations, and most of the times, we need to set a trade-off between memory usage and calculation speed. By the way, it seems that swapping the iterators would need less time compared to removing and attaching the elements. But if you want to use the `iter_swap` function from `<algorithm>` header, the procedure would be much more complicated and sophisticated. Although I didn't give it much thought

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided us with any of your code, can I suggest a different approach (that I don't know will work for your particular situation)?

I would use an algorithm based on your matrix to transpose your values into the new matrix yourself. Since performance is an issue this will help even more so since you don't have to create another matrix. If this is applicable for you.

Have a vector

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Create your matrix

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
```

Reorder vector without another matrix

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Overwrite the values in the current matrix (so you don't have to create a new one) and reorder the values based on your current matrix.

Add values in order

```
R1 and C1 to transposed_vector[0]
R2 and C1 to transposed_vector[1]
R3 and C1 to transposed_vector[2]
R4 and C1 to transposed_vector[3]
R1 and C2 to transposed_vector[4]
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

For non square matrix representation, I think it may be tricky, and not worth the effort to make the transpose of your flat vector without creating another one. Here is a snippet of what I came up with:

```
chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
int i, j, p, k;
vector<int> t_matrix(matrix.size());
for(k=0; k< R*C ;++k)
{
    i = k/C;
    j = k - i*C;
    p = j*R + i;
    t_matrix[p] = matrix[k];
}
cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds> chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count() << endl;
```

Here, `matrix` is your flat vector, `t_matrix` is the "transposed" flat vector, and `R` and `C` are, respectively rows and vector you found for your matrix representation.

Comment: I understand that inplcae transposition could be slower. I need to do inplace transposition because my vector is huge and I can't afford to hold 2 vectors in memory.